# Python program keeps printing "quit" when I just want it to end

Tags: python, syntax

the program below will not stop printing "quit"

```
myvar = str("")
while myvar.lower() != "quit":
    myvar = raw_input()
    print myvar
```

Thanks

Comment: Any chance `raw_input` is returning the string, "quit," with `^M` or a newline appended?

Comment: Also, doing `myvar = str("")` is unnecessary as you can just do `myvar = ""`.

Comment: This works fine in Python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order.

```
myvar = raw_input()
while myvar.lower() != "quit":
    print myvar 
    myvar = raw_input()
```

Comment: ok so you assigned the value of 'raw_input()' to myvar. and that alone make the program not print quit when the user inputs "quit"?

Comment: Because if myvar equals to 'quit', then the program will jump out of the loop and terminate. In your code, the program must print myvar before ending the loop.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `while True:` loop and then break it when `myvar.lower() == "quit"`:

```
# Loop continuously
while True:   
    # Get the input                  
    myvar = raw_input()
    # When converted to lowercase, if the input equals "quit"...
    if myvar.lower() == "quit":
        # ...break the loop
        break
    # If we get here, then myvar.lower() != "quit"
    # So, print the input
    print myvar
```

Comment: it said that "true" is not defined thats why I wasnt using a while true loop.

Comment: `True` must be capitalized.

Comment: @user3015794 - `True` is a built-in in Python.  Meaning, it will always be there.  Make sure it is capitalized.

Comment: @user3015794 - Or, if you want, do this instead:  `while 1:`  It works because every number save `0` evaluates to `True` in Python.